# Add a point with 20ms interval, is possible?

Tags: javascript, performance, highcharts

Data from a sensor is drawn with Highcharts in real time. The sample frequncey of the sensor is 50Hz.
And the requirements: 20ms display a data, curve shift left, no displaying pause.
the only way is to use " addpoint()" function， but when the interval is 20ms, the display curve is stucked.

```
events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each 20 millionsecond
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = date, // date time
                        y = Math.random();
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 20);
```

The question is can the Highchart handle displaying data at such a high frequency?
Also, can the boot.js module improve the performance ?

Comment: seems to working fine with a 20ms timeout in their stock live data chart, can you reproduce your bug in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4syw2d9m/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example of how you can add points every 20ms

```
// Create chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      animation: false
    }
  }
})

// Add points every 20ms
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  chart.series[0].addPoint(50 * (i % 3), false, false, false);
  i += 1;
}, 20)

// Redraw in 60Hz frequency
setInterval(function() {
  chart.redraw(false)
}, 1000 / 60)

// Clear data
setInterval(function() {
    if(chart.series[0].data.length > 1000) {
    chart.series[0].setData([])
  }
  chart.redraw(false)
}, 1000)
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ak3otr5e/

Comment: thanks ,it is worked.  But the websocket is used for ctonnecting the server,  it is stucked still. why?

Comment: If the solution answers your question remember to accept it ;) For websocket data just replace block of code with adding points with your socket listener: ```chart.series[0].addPoint(yourValueFromSocket), false, false, false);```